# Typescript check not done correctly when used in JS constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm using TypeScript to detect typing problems in plain JavaScript. This is possible via a limited set of [JSDoc tags](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript).

However, there's one strange issue with it. When a member is created in the constructor, its type isn't set.

In the screenshot below, VS Code complains correctly about assigning a number to a string inside the `update` method, and directly on an instance. But it doesn't notice the incorrect assignment in the constructor.

This only seems to happen in the constructor, as creating a member in the `update` method does mark the typing issue.

Is there a way to force these type checks also in the constructor?

[image: VS Code view with squiggles]

Code:

```
// @ts-check

function MyClass() {
    /** @type {string} */
    this.str = 0;
};

MyClass.prototype.update = function() {
    this.str = 0
    /** @type {number} */
    this.num = ""
}

let inst = new MyClass()
inst.str = 0
inst.num = ""
```

Comment: Please don't use images for code.

Comment: Have you tried using `@member {string}`?

Comment: `@member` isn't supported for TypeScript. I did try it, but then it doesn't complain about anything. And the reason I used an image is because otherwise it won't show the squiggles. But I'll add the code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/** @constructor */` above `function MyClass` to check it as a constructor.  See [the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSDoc-support-in-JavaScript#constructor).

Comment: Thank you, completely missed that part.